# ¿Cómo funciona el operador "," en C?

Tags: c, operador

Tengo entendido que el operador coma evalua la primera expresión y luego la segunda retornando el valor de la segunda. Haciendo unas pruebas (debido a que estoy aprendiendo) probé con el siguiente código:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int a,b,c;
    printf("Select two numbers: a,b");
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    c = a>=b,50;
    printf("%d", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Y veo que lo que almacena en la variable c es el valor binario de la primera expresión en vez del segundo valor (50). La pregunta es, ¿Aquí que ocurre? ¿Cómo funciona el operador "," en cada escenario? ¿Cúando sería apropiado su uso y cómo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El operador "," para que evalue la primera expresion y retorne la segunda ambas deben estar entre parentesis ( ) asi:

```
c = ( a >= b, 50 );
```

Lo que estaba ocurriendo es que solo tomaba el verdadero o falso de la primera expresion, obviando la segunda ya que no estaba tomandola en cuenta al no estar entre parentesis.

La misma pregunta tambien fue respondida en ingles: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do

Espero que te sirva!

Comment: Mmmm, vale, ahora funciona, pero, ¿Por qué es útil esto? Me refiero a que igual se puede colocar las dos expresiones en líneas separadas.

Comment: te sirve para ahorrar codigo en ciertas partes, pero se aplica mejor cuando haces cambios a la variable, por ejemplo la primera expresion es un incremento y en la segunda realizas una suma y devolves esa suma.