# Problema con igualdades en if c++

Tags: c++

Buenas estoy programando el juego de piedra,papel,tijera,lagarto,spock

Y me surge el siguiente problema, cada opcion tiene su valor dado por el usuario y generado por el ordenador, por que al escribir el siguiente codigo, me dice que he ganado para todos los valores?

```
int jugadausuario,jugadapc;
srand(time(NULL));
cout<<"Bienvenido, jugamos? :) "<<endl;
cout<<" [1] Piedra" <<endl<<" [2] Papel"<<endl<<" [3] Tijeras"<<endl<<" [4] Lagarto"<<endl<<" [5] Spock"<<endl;
cout<<"Seleccione el valor de su jugada: ";
cin>>jugadausuario;
jugadapc=1+rand()%5;


if(jugadausuario==jugadapc)
    cout<<"Han empatado";

else if(jugadausuario==1&&jugadapc==3,4)
    cout<<"Has ganado";
else
    cout<<"Has perdido";
```

En este caso por ejemplo, quiero decir que si el jugador elige piedra, y el ordenador escoge tijera o lagarto, he ganado, pero para cualquier valor  gano,

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo funciona el operador "," en C?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/380268/c%c3%b3mo-funciona-el-operador-en-c)

Comment: Entonces como se podría expresar lo que estoy buscando? por que con el operador || tampoco funciona

Answer (score 0):

Te he modificado el código, ahí explico donde debes de realizar el cambio, tambien muestro el valor de la jugada de la PC para que veas el numero que se genera en cada ronda. Basta con agregar OR a tu condición para que evalúe si cumple al menos una de las condiciones de la derecha y la condición de la izquierda

```
int jugadausuario,jugadapc;
srand(time(NULL));
cout<<"Bienvenido, jugamos? :) "<<endl;
cout<<" [1] Piedra" <<endl<<" [2] Papel"<<endl<<" [3] Tijeras"<<endl<<" [4] Lagarto"<<endl<<" [5] Spock"<<endl;
cout<<"Seleccione el valor de su jugada: ";
cin>>jugadausuario;
jugadapc=1+rand()%5;

if(jugadausuario==jugadapc)
    cout<<"Han empatado Tu elección"<<jugadausuario<<" Eleccion PC: "<<jugadapc";

else if(jugadausuario==1&&(jugadapc==3 || jugadapc==4))//DEBES AGREGAR DE ESTA FORMA LA CONDICION
    cout<<"Has ganado: Tu elección"<<jugadausuario<<" Eleccion PC: "<<jugadapc;
else
    cout<<"Has perdido Tu elección"<<jugadausuario<<" Eleccion PC: "<<jugadapc;

return 0;
```